# What is wrong with this MySQL query? right syntax for INNER_JOIN WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT core_student.STUDENT_ID, core_student.FIRST_NAME, core_student.LAST_NAME
FROM `core_student`
INNER_JOIN `ssp_student`
WHERE ssp_student.STUDENT_ID = core_student.STUDENT_ID;
```

throws an error on the `WHERE` clause:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near 'ssp_student' WHERE ssp_student.STUDENT_ID = core_student.STUDENT_ID`

I just want to select the fields listed in the `SELECT`, then join all columns from `ssp_student` where the `ssp_student.STUDENT_ID` field is the same as the `core_student.STUDENT_ID` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is

```
SELECT core_student.STUDENT_ID, core_student.FIRST_NAME, core_student.LAST_NAME
FROM `core_student`
INNER JOIN `ssp_student`
on ssp_student.STUDENT_ID = core_student.STUDENT_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response -- still throwing an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\`ssp_student\`
on ssp_student.STUDENT_ID = core_student.STUDENT_ID`

Comment: are u executing via some script if yes check if you are adding some single quote. The query should work unless field names are not correct. Try directly on mysql and see.

Comment: I'm just doing this through phpmyadmin query window. Field names are correct.

Comment: hmm there is no _ in INNER_JOIN it should be just INNER JOIN

Comment: That solves that problem, thanks! Although it is not behaving how I expected it to -- I wanted to select those 3 columns from core_student, then all the columns from ssp_student where ssp_student.STUDENT_ID matches core_student.STUDENT_ID. this query only shows the STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME fields.

Comment: just make it `select *` instead of specific field names this will do what u needed.

Comment: I would like to only have the STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME fields from `core_student`, and not have the duplicate `STUDENT_ID` field shown from `ssp_student` -- is there any way I can do this?

Comment: yes in that case u need to do the way u are doing and then in the select list add `ssp_student.colname` which u need to display.